# Why do I get "0 - Unknown Error [object ProgressEvent]" errors?

Tags: node.js, angular, mongodb, integration, project

I have downloaded this file of the repository(https://github.com/zeeshan87/Server-side-Development-with-NodeJS-Express-and-MongoDB/tree/master/Final%20Integrating%20Client%20and%20Server) that is an Angular project combined with NodeJS server for backend part, and tried to run the integrated version of the project. in the Angular part it seems it works fine, but I don't know how exactly run the node server part?

I tried to create a file named `data` inside `..\Final Integrating Client and Server\conFusionServer` folder, then ran `mongod --dbpath=data --bind_ip 127.0.0.1` and it seems it works also fine with the following result:

```
2020-02-03T21:08:28.069+0330 I CONTROL  [main] Automatically disabling TLS 1.0, to force-enable TLS 1.0 specify --sslDisabledProtocols 'none'
2020-02-03T21:08:28.074+0330 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=8660 port=27017 dbpath=data 64-bit host=DESKTOP-UQ8B9FK
2020-02-03T21:08:28.074+0330 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] targetMinOS: Windows 7/Windows Server 2008 R2
2020-02-03T21:08:28.074+0330 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v4.0.10
2020-02-03T21:08:28.075+0330 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: c389e7f69f637f7a1ac3cc9fae843b635f20b766
2020-02-03T21:08:28.075+0330 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
2020-02-03T21:08:28.075+0330 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: none
2020-02-03T21:08:28.075+0330 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] build environment:
2020-02-03T21:08:28.075+0330 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distmod: 2008plus-ssl
2020-02-03T21:08:28.075+0330 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: x86_64
2020-02-03T21:08:28.076+0330 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64
2020-02-03T21:08:28.076+0330 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: { net: { bindIp: "127.0.0.1" }, storage: { dbPath: "data" } }
2020-02-03T21:08:28.079+0330 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] Detected data files in data created by the 'wiredTiger' storage engine, so setting the active storage engine to 'wiredTiger'.
2020-02-03T21:08:28.079+0330 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] wiredtiger_open config: create,cache_size=7627M,session_max=20000,eviction=(threads_min=4,threads_max=4),config_base=false,statistics=(fast),log=(enabled=true,archive=true,path=journal,compressor=snappy),file_manager=(close_idle_time=100000),statistics_log=(wait=0),verbose=(recovery_progress),
2020-02-03T21:08:28.369+0330 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger message [1580751508:368748][8660:140711408328272], txn-recover: Main recovery loop: starting at 5/6528 to 6/256
2020-02-03T21:08:28.491+0330 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger message [1580751508:490742][8660:140711408328272], txn-recover: Recovering log 5 through 6
2020-02-03T21:08:28.594+0330 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger message [1580751508:593742][8660:140711408328272], txn-recover: Recovering log 6 through 6
2020-02-03T21:08:28.653+0330 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger message [1580751508:652710][8660:140711408328272], txn-recover: Set global recovery timestamp: 0
2020-02-03T21:08:28.923+0330 I RECOVERY [initandlisten] WiredTiger recoveryTimestamp. Ts: Timestamp(0, 0)
2020-02-03T21:08:29.057+0330 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]
2020-02-03T21:08:29.057+0330 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: Access control is not enabled for the database.
2020-02-03T21:08:29.060+0330 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          Read and write access to data and configuration is unrestricted.
2020-02-03T21:08:29.061+0330 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]
2020-02-03T21:08:29.459+0330 I FTDC     [initandlisten] Initializing full-time diagnostic data capture with directory 'data/diagnostic.data'
2020-02-03T21:08:29.463+0330 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] waiting for connections on port 27017
```

But when I go to `http://localhost:4200` to see the project, I get `0 - Unknown Error [object ProgressEvent]` errors when loading the page elements!

It seems the connection between Angular and Node.JS isn't established but how can I fix it?